# how to append data in existing array element without overwriting the data in element

Tags: c, arrays, append

so I have two arrays of integers. i need to multiply them but for that i need to store each step's result in a temporary array's element. for example:

say arrays are:

arf[2] = {1, 2};

ars[2] = {3, 2};

tmp[20]; // temporary array for each step

res[20]; // stores each step result in an element

now for multiplication we first do 2*2 and store it in **tmp**[1],
then 2*1 and store it in **tmp**[0], 
answer is 24. now i need to store 24 in first element of **res** array. so **res**[0] = 24. the same goes for 3 * 12. i know i need to do it with a for loop. I store tmp[1] in res[0] next i need to append tmp[0] to res[0] but it overwrites it.

c in this case is 2 because arf and ars each has 2 elements.

```
for (k = c - 1; k >= 0; k--)
        {
            res[i] = tmp[k];
        }
```

So How do i append data in existing element without overwritting data in it?

Comment: can you be more clear the thing you are telling is confusing"now for multiplication we first do 2*2 and store it in tmp[1], then 2*1 and store it in tmp[0], answer is 24." i m not getting how answer is coming 24?

Comment: @Ankur Patel: OP is trying to implement normal multiplication where the arrays represent the numbers as lists of digits.

Comment: `for(k = 0; k < c; ++k) res[i] = res[i]*10 + tmp[k];`

Comment: 2*2 = 4; 2*1=2; it's backward loop so it makes 24.

Comment: I could really use some help.

Answer (score 0):

```
int myMult(int[] num1, int num1Size, int[] num2, int num2Size)
{
  //reverse the arrays so exponent work simplifies
  int newNum1[num1Size];
  for(int i = 0; i < num1Size; i++)
    newNum1[i] = num1[num1Size - 1 - i];
  int newNum2[num2Size];
  for(int i = 0; i < num1Size; i++)
    newNum2[i] = num2[num2Size - 1 - i];

  //create an array to store temporary values
  int temp[num1Size + num2size];
  for(int i = 0; i < num1Size + num2Size; i++)
    temp[i] = 0;

  //perform multiplication digit-wise
  for(int j = 0; j < num2Size; j++;)
  {
    //multiply the given digit through the first number
    for(int i = 0; i < num1Size; i++)
      //add the result to the location in temp, don't replace it
      temp[i+j] += newNum1[i] * newNum2[j];
  }

  //add up the values stored in temp
  int result = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < num1Size + num2Size; i++)
    result += temp[i] * pow(10, i);

  return result;
}
```

The nested loops work as follows:

1. Start with the ones place of the second number (in your example, 2)
2. Multiply that value through the first number and store results in temp (temp[0] = 2*2 + 0 = 4, temp[1] = 2*1 + 0 = 2)
3. Repeat with the tens place, but shift over where you add the results (temp[1] = 3*2 + 2 = 8, temp[2] = 3*1 + 0 = 3;)

The array temp represents each digit of your result. For instance, temp[0] represents the ones place, and temp[1] represents the tens place. When you add up the values of the array, you take into account the place value.

In your example, we have temp[] = {4, 8, 3};
Thus, when we add through temp, we get:

4*10^0 + 8*10^1 + 3*10^2 = 4 + 80 + 300 = 384, which is what it should be.

Hope this helps

Note: I wrote out this answer before I realized this was C and not C++. My syntax may be a little off, but the logic itself should be sound.